# Capturar eventos de la barra de navegacion

Tags: android, android-layout

Se puede capturar y bloquear los eventos de back, home,tarea del navigation bar.

O ocultarlo y que **no aparezca nunca**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes capturar los eventos dentro del método onKeyDown(), por ejemplo el boton back:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        //Se activo la tecla back!
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

el boton home

```
   if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
       //Se activo la tecla home!
    }
```

El tercer boton desconozco como se pueda realizar, anteriores APIs no permitian el control de este boton.